# How to cancel test subscription in Google play developer console

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, developer-console, in-app-subscription

I initially had test accounts for testing in -app purchases in android but I since removed the testing accounts and moved the app from beta to production. Both test accounts have attempted to cancel their test subscriptions through the Google play app according to documentation. Although the Google play app says the subscription had canceled, it still remains active. Even with trying to uninstall the app. How can I remove the test subscriptions?

I have removed the beta test apk from the Play Store and disabled testing. I have removed all testing accounts from the licensing page as well as the authorized beta testers list. Beta test users are still reporting having an active (daily) test subscription. No matter how many times they hit cancel, it still renews the next day. I need to get this removed. It is hindering our development process.

Comment: I wonder if we have to wait for the subscription period to end (in the case of testing subscriptions, 1 day). After canceling, does it work the next day?

Comment: Yes. I've tried cancelling the sub and uninstalling then waiting till the next day. It still charges the test sub

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're testing with real transactions where you got a token when you subscribed, you can try cancelling subscription using Google Play Developer API > [Cancel Subscription](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/cancel)

> **Purchases.subscriptions: cancel**
>
> ```
> Cancels a user's subscription purchase. The subscription remains valid until its expiration time.
> ```
>
> **HTTP request**
>
> **POST**
>   https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/**packageName**/purchases/subscriptions/**subscriptionId**/tokens/**token**:cancel
>
> where
>
> **packageName**   string  The package name of the application for which this
>   subscription was purchased (for example, 'com.some.thing').
>
> **subscriptionId**    string  The purchased subscription ID (for example, 'monthly001').
>
> **token** string  The token provided to the user's device
>   when the subscription was purchased.

The API requires [authorisation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/cancel#auth).

Also check [this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)

**Canceling completed test purchases**

> Google Play accumulates completed test purchases for each user but
>   does not pass them on to financial processing.
>
> In some cases, you might want to manually cancel a test purchase to
>   continue testing. To do so, open the app page in the Play Store. If
>   the test purchase that you want to cancel is a subscription, you can
>   also use the cancel() method of the Purchases.subscriptions API.

Comment: Transactions are "daily " test transactions. No matter what I've tried or how many times the subscription is canceled, it doesn't go away. :/

Comment: Have you tried cancel() method of the Purchases.subscriptions API?

Comment: If you mean after hosting the api on my server then no. I haven't tried that. I've tried everything through the play console or the play store app.

Comment: I've even gone as far as removing the beta apk and disabling beta

Comment: You dont need to host the API initially if there are small no. of test users. You can create APIs Console project as described in Authorisation link, get redirect uri and  client id from project and use them to get access token. Once you have this access token you can use it to cancel subscription using cancel API.

Comment: Authorization is a pain. How to do it?

Comment: how is the result ?